# getting the list of countries which have more than one official language

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I tried to find the all the country from dbpedia which have more than one official language. i tried the following sparql query but did not work.

```
SELECT distinct ?country ?officialLanguage
WHERE {
  ?country rdf:type dbo:Country .
  ?country dbo:officialLanguage ?officialLanguage. 

 FILTER (COUNT(?officialLanguage) >1)
}
```

and got the following error-

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 8: Aggregates are allowed only in result sets at ')' before '>'
```

I am very new to sparql. I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative query to the answer of @svick you could try

```
SELECT ?country (COUNT(?officialLanguage) AS ?nrOfLanguages)
WHERE {
  ?country rdf:type dbo:Country .
  ?country dbo:officialLanguage ?officialLanguage. 
}
GROUP BY ?country 
HAVING(COUNT(?officialLanguage) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

SPARQL doesn't work like that, it can't deduce that you mean the count of distinct `?officialLanguage` for each `?country`. You will need to be more explicit than that, for example:

```sql
SELECT distinct ?country ?officialLanguage
WHERE {
  ?country rdf:type dbo:Country .
  ?country dbo:officialLanguage ?officialLanguage.
  {
      SELECT ?country COUNT(*) AS ?languages
      WHERE {
          ?country dbo:officialLanguage [].
      }
  }

  FILTER (?languages > 1)
}
```

Comment: This query is not optimal as it 1) does not use legal SPARQL (there is no comma in SPARQL for multiple variables) 2) does not perfectly reflect the goal.

Comment: @AKSW 1. That is trivial to fix, thanks for letting me know. 2. Could you explain what do you mean by that? If you mean that the query should not return the languages, then that reflects the goal of what's explicitly written in the question, but I think it does not reflect the goal of the invalid code.